# Datepicker To Only Display Months

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, datepicker

I have a datepicker which I only want the user to be able to select a month and year.

The user should only be able to select up to a year from todays date.  I have this working but I cant seem to get only the months displaying.

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-groups">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" name="idTourDateDetails" id="idTourDateDetails" class="form-control clsDatePicker">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Script**

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
    $('#idTourDateDetails').datepicker({
        format: "mm-yyyy",
        startMode: "months", 
        minViewMode: "months",
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        minDate: '0d',
        maxDate: '1y'
    });
</script>
```

I tried adding `data-date-format="mm-yyyy"` to the `input` but it didn't work.

See working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RQgCW/103/)

I do not want to just hide the calendar, I want the dates to display the months instead.  Other suggestion below only hide the calendar.

This [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RWY2X/2/) is what I'm after but I can't get it working as when I put the HTML and the JQuery into my solution, I get the dates still displayed.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bopperben/DBpJe/ see this

Comment: @dreamweiver Rather than display the dates I want to display the month not completely hide the calendar as all the suggestions in that stack show

Comment: @Pekka Please see comment above, I want the months to display rather than dates and I want only the 'Year' to be displayed at the top

Comment: `$(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date( month, 1));` <---- is this what you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of datepicker you can use month picker where you can select only year and month, you can refer https://github.com/KidSysco/jquery-ui-month-picker where they have given detailed documentation and fiddle link.